# openvpn - Why do I have 2 tun interfaces on my server?

Tags: openvpn, ifconfig, tun

I have just configured watching this [Hak5 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcsQdtsCS1U) I found on Youtube.

But what is bothering me is that why do I have two tun interfaces on my server ?

Namely-:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

As you can see they both have same inet addresses.

Also why I grep the openvpn process I get two pids returned to me, is that normal ?

```
root@ip-VPS:/etc/openvpn# pgrep openvpn
1681
1691
```

Any clue as to why this is happening ? What am I doing wrong ?

My server.conf is the following-:

```
port 53
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

The output of `ps -ef | grep openvpn` is the following-:

```
root      1185     1  0 04:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server.orig --status /run/openvpn/server.orig.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/server.orig.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.orig.pid
nobody    1241     1  0 04:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid
root      1577  1517  0 04:48 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto openvpn
```

Comment: Did you start two copies of openvpn?

Comment: Post your relevant configuration files and please don't expect us to visit an external video to come up with an idea what you might have done wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHampton No all I was `service openvpn start`.

Comment: @Sven I have included the server.conf file from /etc/openvpn. What other files do you need ?

Comment: Add output of `ps -ef | grep [o]penvpn`. Do you have any other `*.conf` files in the `/etc/openvpn`?

Comment: @rda Did what you asked. Also the only other `.conf` file in `/etc/openvpn`is `update-resolv.conf`. I did not touch it, do you still want me to post it ?

Comment: It's exactly what I suspected, you have two copies of openvpn running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 copies of openvpn running because you have 2 valid config files

> /etc/openvpn/server.orig.conf 
>   /etc/openvpn/server.conf

You should have renamed the first such that it does not end with a .conf e.g. `/etc/openvpn/server.conf.orig` because by default openvpn creates an instance for each valid config file that it finds in the /etc/openvpn.